prove that $\frac{x^x}{|x-y|} + \frac{y^y}{|y-z|} + \frac{z^z}{|z-x|} \geqslant \frac{7}{2}.$ where $x \neq y \neq z$
Question Statement:
I came across the following intriguing inequality problem involving positive real numbers $x$, $y$, and $z$, where $x \neq y \neq z$:
$$\frac{x^x}{|x-y|} + \frac{y^y}{|y-z|} + \frac{z^z}{|z-x|} \geqslant \frac{7}{2}.$$

Attempt First, I noted the unusual form of the terms involving $x$, $y$, and $z$, each raised to their respective powers.
My initial approach involved trying to use the AM-GM inequality and  Cauchy-Schwarz(I did not tried BW) inequality to establish a relationship between the terms in the inequality
However, the absolute values in the denominators posed a challenge in applying these standard inequaliti directly Moreover the distinctness of $x$, $y$, and $z$ adds complexity to the problem
Despite various attempts and manipulations, I haven't been able to find a direct path to prove the desired inequality.
maybe we need good software

This is the same question although without a satisfactory answer.

May you share the source of the question?

@Sahaj the book of Ychangheo (will be published in 2030)

@Sahaj Yeah, I realize this is an old question, but since it didn't receive a satisfactory answer, I decided to repost it. Otherwise, commenting on the original post would be pointless.

Technically we need to prove $$\bigg(\frac{x^xy^yz^z}{|(x-y)(y-z)(z-x)|}\bigg)^\frac13-\frac23≥\frac12$$

@Gwen can you elaborate more?
